# How to vertically middle align image and text in Microsoft Outlook 2007?

Tags: email, outlook, alignment

I'm coding for a HTML email template, and need to vertically align an image with text next to it. The code is like:

`<img style="vertical-align: middle" src="images/abc.png" width="20" height="20" border="0" alt=""> Text Text Text`

However, that works in web email agents like Gamil and Yahoo Mail, but not in Microsoft Outlook 2007.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same question and I fixed it by using tables. I aligned the image by using the valign="middle" attribute. You can also use the css property vertical-align.

```
<td valign="middle"><img src="cid:myimage.png" title="dummy" /></td>
<td>The text to be shown next to the image</td>
```